# ¿Cómo pasar una fecha en formato YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS a dd-mm-yyyy con javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Tengo una fecha en formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` y quiero pasarlo a formato `dd-mm-yyyy` con javascript, se como se puede hacer en el servidor, pero quiero hacerlo en el cliente. Pensaba en partir la fecha en el espacio que hay en el string pero no se si haya un método mas directo para hacerlo.

Saludos.

La forma en la que resolví esto fue la siguiente.

```js
var fecha ="2019-07-01 12:00:00";
var nueva =fecha.split(" ")[0];
var format = nueva.split("-");
var ultima = format[2]+'-'+format[1] +'-'+format[0]
console.log(ultima);
```

Estuve investigando y al parecer javascript no ha agregado funciones para manejar fechas que provengan de bases de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes una fecha en una cadena con formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` y quieres pasarlo a formato `dd-mm-yyyy` con javascript puedes hacerlo de manera simple con las funciones `split()`, `reverse()` y `join()` de la siguiente forma:

```js
var fecha="2019-07-01 12:00:00";
console.log(fecha);
var nueva=fecha.split(" ")[0].split("-").reverse().join("-");
console.log(nueva);
```

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo resolví de otra forma pero la tuya es más compacta. Me imagino que javascript no a integrado funciones para formatear fechas de bases de datos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con `toLocaleDateString()`

```js
let date= new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

que tal?

Pues yo te recomiendo una libreria que es muy pero que muy usada y te va ayudar en muchas cosas aparte de en formatear la fecha. Se llama [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment.locale();          // en
moment().format('L');    // 07/01/2019
moment().format('l');    // 7/1/2019
moment().format('LL');   // July 1, 2019
moment().format('ll');   // Jul 1, 2019

moment.locale();         // es
moment().format('l');    // 1/7/2019
moment().format('LL');   // 1 de julio de 2019
moment().format('ll');   // 1 de jul. de 2019
moment().format('LLL');  // 1 de julio de 2019 21:41
```

Cambiando tu zone consigues el resultado que necesitas